# Test planning/documentation/management tools

Tags: testing, test-plan

I'm looking for a good, preferably free, test planning and documentation tool. Ideally something that will keep track of which tests have been run against which software version, with reporting ability. There's a whole bunch of tools listed [here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/testmgt.php) but are there any others, and which ones have you had the best experience with? (You do run tests, right?)

**UPDATE 2008-01-29**

So far [TestLink](http://testlink.sourceforge.net/docs/testLink.php) and [Fitness](http://fitnesse.org/) have been mentioned. [A related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166103/free-program-for-building-managing-test-plans) yielded also a link to the [ReadySet](http://readyset.tigris.org/) project, an open collection of software planning documentation templates.

I have used TestLink and found it okayish, but I cannot say I enjoyed using it. Has anyone had any experience with Fitnesse? Or are there any other free tools out there that you have used and found satisfactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used QualityCenter/TestDirectory for a long time.

I'm now using testlink and I must say that I prefer QualityCenter/TestDirectory by far, even if it based on some buggy ActiveX control.

QualityCenter/TestDirectory is more easier to use and the interface is quite better.

TestLink and QualityCenter/TestDirectory are mainly for manual test case (however, you can use Quick Test Pro on QualityCenter/TestDirectory to automatize your tests).

Fitnesse is another kind of tool in my mind : basically, you write your test case on a wiki and link that to a JUnit test. Another tools like that are GreenPepper, Concordion, etc.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that QualityCenter/TestDirector are the very opposite of free. In fact, all the places I've worked that have used it have severely limited access to it on grounds of cost per seat, which IMHO has made it a much less useful tool.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely try out Klaros-Testmanagement http://www.klaros-testmanagement.com which has an free, unrestricted Community Edition.

Comment: Klaros is pretty sweet for a free software!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we do run tests, but not nearly as many as I'd like !

I highly recommend [TestLink](http://testlink.sourceforge.net/docs/testLink.php) - the list of tools that you linked to shows that it's had more downloads than all of the other tools put together.

Answer (score 2):

PractiTest is a very good option. Not free but very affordable  - http://www.practitest.com

Answer (score 2):

A little late on this one, but I would have to suggest you try [TestLodge](http://www.testlodge.com) for your manual test management. It works in a simular way to what TestLink does, but it gives off a more professional interface and is something that we also allow our clients to use for their uat phase.

Comment: TestLodge isn't free, but has very competitive pricing. Also the support/dev team is very responsive. It had the best usability and UI of all alternatives I evaluated. I found it to be the best solution for our Test Management needs at our startup.

Answer (score 1):

We use Quality Center / Test Director stuff. Its expensive as far as I know, and it's not that great.

Comment: Definitely agree with the not that great part :)

Comment: :) Our testdepartment is ok with it, in so much that it doesnt keep them from doing their work and the reports and defectmanagement gives usefull "stuff"

Comment: I actually started filtering out job ads that mentioned QC last time I was looking for a role.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/) but I don't know how good it's test tracking is.

I *know* I just recently saw a slick looking test tracker for Trac or something, but I can't find it now...

Answer (score 1):

Quality Center. It's expensive, but it is the best

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Patrick - good ol' office tools :)

I just write mine in *Microsoft Word*

This is the structure I developed: [Writing a System Test Plan](http://pm4web.blogspot.com/2008/07/writing-system-test-plan.html).

Answer (score 0):

One thought, and perhaps not a good one, would be to have every test submit a ticket to your ticketing system when it's run indicating the test name, build version, and date, and test results.

That would make the results searchable later-on.

Answer (score 0):

We use a home-grown Access database.

This database keeps track of our requirements, test cases, test plan and test runs. We're able to produce an up-to-date RVTM, keep track of progress against the plan, and assign tasks to testers. We integrated it with Outlook, so each tester is assigned a task from the plan by the QA lead. When they're complete, they just tick it off in Outlook and it updates the database.

For our small team of testers it works nicely, and we're free to customize it however we want.